# Makefile pattern matching failure

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
BINS = $(patsubst %.c, %, $(SRCS))

all: $(BINS)

%: %.o
        $(info ---------- linking $< ---------)
        $(CC) $< -o $@ -L$(LIBPATH) -llibrary
```

Will name in `$(BINS)` match `%`? I need the rule `%: %.o` to be invoked which in turn calls other rule to create `.o`s. But this match is not happening due to which implicit rules are getting triggered.

My goal is to create binaries with same name as their `.c` files with out the extension. `.o`s should be created in the process

Comment: Which rules *are* getting triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might sound drastic, but you should remove *all* rules, then it will work. Yes, I'm serious. `make` has built-in rules to create `foo` from `foo.c` by compiling, since it is so common. Watch it happen:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
$ cat Makefile
cat: Makefile: No such file or directory

$ make CFLAGS=-lm hello
cc -lm  hello.c  -o hello
$ ./hello
hello, world
$
```

More realistically, if you want to compile a set of executables each from their *.c counterpart, all you need in your Makefile is

```
all: prog1 prog2 progN
```

Sweet, ain't it?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
all : ${BINS}

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

$(BINS) : %: %.o
    @echo ---------- linking $< ---------
    $(CC) -o $@ $< -L$(LIBPATH) -llibrary
```

It would be simpler to compile and link in one go:

```
$(BINS) : %: %.c
    @echo ---------- compiling and linking $< ---------
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```